# Magento2-REST-API estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id returns empty array

Tags: rest, magento2

I have configured default country to be India and also configured the shipping methods for store.

Shipping-methods such as **Free-shipping**, **flat-rate** and **table-rate** are configured.

Custom shipping is set as **Off**.

When trying to get the **shipping method** using **Magento2 API**, empty array is returned.

Input Request Details:

Url:
`http:// {{base_url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id`

Authorization: **Bearer {{token}}**

Content-Type: **application/json**

Method:**POST**

Body: **{"addressId": 5}**

**Response**: `[ ]`

What could be issue?

Comment: is this case with your current id or happens with each `addressId` ?

Comment: Its a fresh installation and I am trying to test create an order. I have successfully added items to cart. When trying to checkout, have entered a billing address with flag useForShippingAddress set to true. But when using that address Id to estimate the shipping methods, the empty array is returned.

Comment: What is the status of your shipping methods? Are your shipping methods enabled inside website or store views. Double check if your shipping methods are not enable inside your website, store or store view. 
The empty array is returned when all shipping methods are disabled.

Comment: Hi @Arsalan, The shipping methods are enabled inside website.

Comment: @Arsalan, please find the attached screen-shot of the configuration. Ship to Applicable Countries is set to India in all cases. Also tried with all allowed countries. 
Attachment URL: https://unsee.cc/ba3091b3/

Comment: From your provided screenshot, it seems you have specified each Enabled shipping method for specific countries. Can you try with option "Allowed for All countries" or try checkout with selected countries from option "ship to specific countries"? Make sure you are performing checkout for selected country, like US etc.

Comment: Hi @Arsalan, I have been trying with the JSON

`{
   "cartId":2,
   "address":{
      "city":"Cochin",
      "country_id":"IN",
      "customer_id":2,
      "email":"dev2@mailinator.com",
      "firstname":"DEV",
      "lastname":"One",
      "postcode":"682037",
      "region":"Kerala",
      "region_code":"KL",
      "region_id":550,
      "same_as_billing":1,
      "save_in_address_book":1,
      "street":[
         "House1",
         "Vijayanagar",
         "Aluva"
      ],
      "telephone":"8492382332"
   },
   "userForShipping":true
}`

Anything wrong in this?

Comment: Hi @Arsalan, I have tried with both "Allowed for All countries" and "ship to specific countries" set to India. Also tried with all countries option

Comment: Hi @Arsalan I have tried for API `rest/V1/carts/mine/billing-address` with the json